# Core supported script for deploying tornado app to aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tornado, wsgi

There are some small bits of boiler-plate for configuring tornado apps to run on ebs.

I haven't found one -  is a core group supported script for generating the boiler plate code + firing off the deployment?

(I'm new to Tornado - maybe I'm off in a strange corner of the world, and this is too trivial to be worth having a tool for?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you have in mind -- there is a whole array of ways to deploy a Tornado app, from manual upload to CI. Can you give more details on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: There aren't any more details - literally any of the methods would suffice, as long as there is a matching core supported script for generating config + deploying to ebs

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking -- what do you mean by "matching core support script"?